# fmsb - Radar chart function. Missing polygons in some of the radar plots, in grid

Tags: r, plot

I'm having a weird issue with the radar chart function from the fmsb R package. I'm trying to create a grid with a separate plot for each row using the following code.

```
avgsol <- avg %>% select(-group)
avgsol <- rbind(rep(100,17) , rep(0,17) , avgsol)
# Prepare color

colors_border=colormap(colormap=colormaps$viridis, nshades=6, alpha=1)
colors_in=colormap(colormap=colormaps$viridis, nshades=6, alpha=0.3)

# Prepare title
mytitle <- c("Baseline", "3Hz", "7Hz", "8Hz", "10Hz", "13Hz", "15Hz","19Hz")

# Split the screen in 6 parts
par(mar=rep(0.8,4))
par(mfrow=c(2,4))

# Loop for each plot
for(i in 1:8){
  
  # Custom the radarChart !
  radarchart( avgsol[c(1,2,i+2),], axistype=0, 
              
              #custom polygon
              pcol=colors_border[i] , pfcol=colors_in[i] , plwd=4, plty=1 , 
              
              #custom the grid
              cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="grey", caxislabels=seq(0,20,5), cglwd=0.8,
              
              #custom labels
              vlcex=0.8,
              
              #title
              title=mytitle[i]
  )
}
```

avg just contains a row of 8 rows of numeric data over 16 columns. Not sure why most of the plot of works but the last part breaks.

[Plot that I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/134ek.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was in my color palette(colors_border and colors_in), so the last two conditions just kept being plotted transparently. Added the changed code if anyone ends up with the same problem as me. Essentially the colormap function was set to only put out 6 colors so the other 2 ended up being transparent.

colors_border=colormap(colormap=colormaps$viridis, nshades=8, alpha=1)
colors_in=colormap(colormap=colormaps$viridis, nshades=8, alpha=0.3)